# How to realize inline images in RTE in TYPO3 8.7

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

I am trying to make inline images in the RTE working.

The extensions I installed are:
rtehtmlarea 8.7.2 and
rte_ckeditor_image  8.9.0 but I tried both in older versions
on TYPO3 8.7.26

My RTE config is this:

```
# Load default processing options
imports:
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Full.yaml" }
    # Import the image plugin configuration
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor_image/Configuration/RTE/Plugin.yaml" }

editor:
  config:
    format_tags: "p;h3;h5"
    removePlugins: null
    externalPlugins:
        typo3image:
          allowedExtensions: "gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg"
    removeButtons:
      - Strike
      - Anchor
      - Outdent
      - Indent
      - Blockquote
      - JustifyBlock
      - JustifyLeft
      - JustifyRight
      - JustifyCenter
      - HorizontalRule
      - BidiLtr
      - BidiRtl
      - Font
      - FontSize
      - Styles
```

In the RTE I get an little image icon as expected. Clicking it opens the the FAL-browser but picking the image causes an js alert with the error message:

> Error - reference to main window is not set properly!

How to debug this? or is there an combination of extensions that works hassle free? Am I missing a configuration step?

Answer (score 2):

you can't use the old `rtehtmlarea` editor and expect that addon extensions and configuration of `rte_ckeditor` will work.

`rtehmlarea` has it's own way to activate images (in the extension configuration).

`rte_ckeditor_image` will need the editor `rte_ckeditor`

If you use/activate both editor extensions you may get conflicts.
maybe you have a javascript error from this conflict (look into the console of your browser for errors)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a question of of extension versions or configuration. It worked when I used Google Chrome instead of Firefox.

Comment: don't use answer for anything other than answering the original question. this is preferrable a comment (like this). For further information: edit your question and add it.